# « Un pis un autre » : détails, tournure équivalente ?

Tags: grammaire, québec, régionalismes, coordination

> On savait que le monde du gin est populaire, mais il y en a **un pis
> un autre** sur les tablettes, commente M. Lavoie. On ne voulait pas
> commercialiser un gin et se diluer dans un océan de produits
> semblables. (dans [LaPresse](https://www.lapresse.ca/gourmand/alcools/2023-03-22/a-boire/distiller-notre-sucre-national.php))

[*Un pis un autre*](https://www.laparlure.com/terme/un-pis-un-autre/) évoque la multitude.

- La locution a-t-elle d'autres connotations que la *multitude*, est-elle employée à l'extérieur de la région de l'Estrie (Québec) et quelle est sa nature : adverbiale ou adjectivale ? ou ;
- Ailleurs qu'au Québec a-t-on une locution employant un procédé
  similaire (coordination de l'indéfini) ; peut-on employer « un autre
  et un autre » de cette manière pour un sens similaire ?

Comment: Dans ce contexte (il s'agit d'une transcription d'une ‘entrevue’ avec un parler régional, *pis* = *p**u**is*

Answer (score 1):

"Un et puis un autre" et j'ajouterais "même un autre de plus." Comme dans "Je cherchais des romans de Jules Verne. Je suis allé à la bibliothèque et j'en ai trouvé un pis un autre". J'en ai trouvé plusieurs, même plus que j'en espérais.

Comment: comme dans l'expression familière "et pis c'est tout" (et puis c'est tout) ?